# jquery templates with play framework

Tags: jquery, playframework

I am a newbie to play and jquery templates.
What I want to do is render the pojo data on click of a div.
need help on the syntax as the data is not getting populated..
what i am trying to do is..which is not working..Need some help on this..

```
<script id="expense" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
         {{=name}}                   
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#invoicelist').click(function(){
        if ($(this).next().is(":hidden")){  
          $.post('bars.json', function(data){
                   $.each(data, function(index, item){
                      // $("#expandeddetails1").show("slow");
                      //$("#expandeddetails1").clone(true)
                      //                      .insertAfter("#expandeddetails1");
                      $("#employeeTemplate").tmpl(item)
                                            .appendTo('#invoicelist');
                   });
          });
        }else{
              $(this).next()
                     .slideUp("slow",function(){ 
                           $("#expandeddetails1").detatch()  
                     });
        }
        return false;   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good for debugging if you share more information.

1. Where is `#employeeTemplate` defined?
2. template `#expense` is not used in any part of the relevant code, do you mean it should be `#employeeTemplate` ?
3. What is the data returned from `bars.json` post call? Did you check in firebug or chrome?

BTW, it gives me a feeling that your $each loop over the data could be simplified as

```
$('#employeeTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#invoicelist');
```

Check more about jquery template on http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/ or even more simple usage at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/